# Keyframes disappeared

Tags: keyframes, timeline

R-type in 2d animation. I even tried all the stuffs like scrolling  and from view section deselecting specific keys like only show keyframes from selected channels, frame all etc  but its still not showing up

Comment: Check if you went back on the timeline: i.e. if a frame was created when the timeline was on frame 50 it will disappear during frames 1-49.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.